# In WindowListener,how to avoid all methods declaration while using a single eventof WindowClosing()?

Tags: java, windows

(WindowClosing) when i am using window event for closing current frame, in that it asked import all abstract methods.. How to import windowClosing event without import all sbstract methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use a [WindowAdapter](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowAdapter.html) instead of a WindowListener.  WindowAdapter is abstract but has no abstract methods (it implements them with empty methods) so that you only override the methods you actually want to work with.

Comment: Worth mentioning that you'll likely end up using WindowAdapter as an anonymous class or an inner class.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [WindowAdapter](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowAdapter.html) - all the Swing listeners have a "stub" implementation that implements the methods of the listener interface with empty methods.  This way you only have to override the methods you need.  Be sure to use the @Override annotation to detect any problems such as method name misspellings / leaving out parameters / etc.

Answer (score 0):

A Frame has different closing possibilities by itself. I assume you found that out, and want to make a `WindowListener` without writing all of the methods which you don't need. In that case, use a `WindowAdapter` which happens to be a `WindowListener` with all methods implemented. You can override the ones you want.